# Navigate always to a specific page though all pages are public in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django, react-hooks, react-router, jwt

I have made a **PrivateRoute** for a specific page. All the pages are public (*Anyone can view them*) except the **PrivateRoute** page. If a user is unauthorized then the route always navigates to the page which is declared in logUser function.

I am using Python Django for building APIs.

app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import Post from "./pages/Post";
import Details from "./pages/Details";
import HeaderNav from "./components/Navbar";
import Footerbar from "./components/Footer";
import PrivateRoute from "./utils/PrivateRoute";
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>
          <HeaderNav />
          <div className="bg-gray-100 w-full h-full">
            <Routes>
              <Route element={<PrivateRoute />} path="/post">
                <Route element={<Post />} path="/post" />
              </Route>
              <Route element={<Home />} path="/" />
              <Route element={<Post />} path="/post" />
              <Route element={<Details />} path="/post/:id" />
              <Route element={<Register />} path="/register" />
              <Route element={<Login />} path="/login" />
            </Routes>
          </div>
          <Footerbar />
        </AuthProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthContext";

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const { username } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return username ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

AuthContext.js

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export default AuthContext;

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  let [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(() =>
    localStorage.getItem("authTokens")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authTokens"))
      : null
  );
  let [username, setUsername] = useState(() =>
    localStorage.getItem("authTokens")
      ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("authTokens"))
      : null
  );
  let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  let loginUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: e.target.username.value,
        password: e.target.password.value,
      }),
    });
    let data = await response.json();

    if (response.status === 200) {
      setAuthTokens(data);
      setUsername(jwt_decode(data.access));
      localStorage.setItem("authTokens", JSON.stringify(data));
      navigate("/");
    } else {
      alert("Incorrect username or password!");
    }
  };

  const logoutUser = () => {
    setAuthTokens(null);
    setUsername(null);
    localStorage.removeItem("authTokens");
    navigate("/"); // Always navigating this page when the user is unauthorized
  };

  const updateToken = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ refresh: authTokens?.refresh }),
      }
    );
    let data = await response.json();
    if (response.status === 200) {
      setAuthTokens(data);
      setUsername(jwt_decode(data.access));
      localStorage.setItem("authTokens", JSON.stringify(data));
    } else {
      logoutUser();
    }

    if (loading) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const contextData = {
    username: username,
    authTokens: authTokens,
    loginUser: loginUser,
    logoutUser: logoutUser,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) updateToken();
    const fourMinutes = 4 * 60 * 1000;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (authTokens) {
        updateToken();
      }
    }, fourMinutes);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [authTokens, loading]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
      {loading ? null : children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

If you see the `logoutUser` function, there which page is navigated, always redirects to this page if the user is unauthorized.

I want to restrict only post page that's why I use `PrivateRoute`. Other pages will be open for all.

I have been stuck for a while and can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthProvider` has a `useEffect` hook that calls `updateToken` on an interval that makes a POST request to update tokens, and when/if there's a non-200 response status the `logoutUser` function is called and resets some auth state and navigates to `"/"`. This all occurs ***regardless*** of the user's current authentication status.

You only want to call `logoutUser` if the user is actually logged in. Because `updateToken` is called from a closure you can use a React ref to cache the current `username` state value to avoid including `username` as a `useEffect` dependency.

```js
const [username, setUsername] = useState(() =>
  localStorage.getItem("authTokens")
    ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("authTokens"))
    : null
);

// React ref to store cached username "auth" state
const usernameRef = React.useRef(username);

// side-effect to cache username state value
useEffect(() => {
  usernameRef.current = username;
}, [username]);
```

```
const updateToken = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ refresh: authTokens?.refresh }),
    }
  );
  let data = await response.json();
  if (response.status === 200) {
    setAuthTokens(data);
    setUsername(jwt_decode(data.access));
    localStorage.setItem("authTokens", JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    // If user is currently authenticated, log them out
    if (usernameRef.current) {
      logoutUser();
    }
  }

  if (loading) {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};
```